# Save object within the save of another object in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model:

```
class OriginalModel(Model):
...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance in self.list:
          model = Model2(id=instance)
          model.save()

    return super(OriginalModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have to save 2 times the same object from the admin (Django CMS) so even the Model2 is saved. I tried it with post_save but still it is the same issue and even tried overwriting the save method of admin model but still cant seem to save it within the first save of the OriginalModel.

I don't want to save the OriginalModel 2 times from the admin site, because it is not at all user friendly. Is it doable only to save once and the Model2 will be saved also?

Comment: You haven't said what the issue is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well i dont want to save the object twice in the django cms, its doesn't make sense :-)